# Maven module doesn't see dependable submodule

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, multi-module

I have following project structure:

```
Root:  
   module_1   
   module_2  
   shared
```

module_1 depends on shared module.

Thus **Root pom.xml** looks like this:

```
<groupId>root</groupId>
<artifactId>root</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>root</name>
<modules>
    <module>module_1</module>
    <module>module_2</module>
    <module>shared</module>
</modules>
```

**module_1 pom.xml:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>root</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**shared pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>root</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>shared</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>shared</name>
<description>shared</description>
```

But when I try to build root project maven outputs compile errors that module_1 doesn't see classes from shared module:

```
[ERROR] Some_class_from module_1 cannot find symbol 
[ERROR] symbol:   Some_class_from_shared_module
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Packaging in shared pom.xml should probably be jar (instead of pom).

Comment: First make the shared project a a jar packaging instead of pom...otherwise it does not make sense having dependencies on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module1`'s dependency on `shared` is of type `pom` ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This means that `module1` will inherit the dependencies of `shared` but it will not have access to any classes within `shared`.

Typically `<type>pom</type>` is associated with `<scope>import</scope>` since this acts to include any dependencies of `shared` in `module1`. In your case you want more that the transitively provided dependencies of `shared`, you want `shared`'s classes too so remove ...

```
<type>pom</type>
```

... this will cause the dependency to use the default type (jar) which will then allow `module1` to depend on (a) `shared`'s dependencies and (b) `shared`'s classes.

Comment: it is working but I want be sure that during the root project building shared moduke wil be rebuild too. Does this approach supports this?

Comment: Are you saying that the above answer fixed your issue? And that now you would like to ask another question: "how can I ensure that the `shared` module is built whenever `module1` is built"?

Comment: `module1` and `shared` are sub modules of `root` so whenever you build `root` Maven will determine which sub modules need to be built and will build them. If however, you choose to build only `module1` then Maven will not build `shared`. So, if your intention is to ensure that the `shared` module is built whenever `module1` is built then just build `root` and let Maven take care of this for you.